# How to set -Xmx for Spring CDF app running on Kubernetes?

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-application-configuration) I should be able to set `-Xmx` of an application with the `deployer.time.memory` property.

I created the following stream definition:

```
dataflow:>stream create --name ticktock --definition "time | log"
```

And I've tried deploying it on my Kubernetes CDF in several ways:

```
dataflow:>stream deploy --name ticktock --properties "deployer.time.memory=2048m"

dataflow:>stream deploy --name ticktock --properties "deployer.time.local.memory=2048m"

dataflow:>stream deploy --name ticktock --properties "deployer.time.local.javaOpts=2048m"
```

After each deployment I've run the following commands:

```
# ps aux | grep time | grep -i xmx
#

# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
52a31b764112        springcloudstream/time-source-rabbit:1.2.0.RELEASE   "java -jar /maven/tim"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes                            k8s_ticktock-time.a4ab30e_ticktock-time-kqckg_default_53b3e059-5049-11e7-a0d4-000c29df937a_3cc76216
```

Why isn't `-Xmx` set on the `time` app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties you refer above are the `local` deployer properties, not the kubernetes deployer properties. For the Kubernetes deployment properties you can refer the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: I thought so at first, but I can't find any chapter for setting -Xmx in it. Does that mean that it isn't possible to set it?

Comment: There are a few options to pass app properties. It is controlled by `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.entryPointStyle` and it takes `exec`, `shell`, or `boot` as the options with the default being `exec`. If this is set as a global deployer property, the `deployer.time.memory` should take into account. Alternatively, if you're trying to override the memory for all the apps, you can use `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.memory` as a global property, too.

Comment: I have set the kubernetes memory limit to 2 GiB for all apps. I would like to set -Xmx from app to app because java in docker doesn't work really well without it. So I don't want to set it globally. `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.entryPointStyle` is default, but you can see from my question that I've passed `deployer.time.memory` but there is no -Xmx passed to java process.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. There's an undocumented `spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.environmentVariables` property that can be used to override memory allocations instead of depending on the defaults. To this property, you can pass options, for example, `JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx2048m` as the value. We will document this via [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes#200](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/issues/200)